# Создать класс Circle

Tags: c++, классы, инспекция-кода

Создать класс окружность
Параметры: координаты центра, радиус. Методы: процедура инициализации полей, процедура вывода на экран значения полей объекта и функция, определяющая, находится ли некоторая точка с координатами x,y внутри окружности.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
class Circle
{
private:
   double x;
   double y;
   double r;
public:
Circle();
   Circle(double xC, double yC, double rad);
   void centre_dist(Circle & c);
};

Circle::Circle()
{
    cout << "Enter x coord: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter y coord: ";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "Enter radius: ";
while (cin >> r && r < 0)
{
  cout << "Radius can't be negative\n";
  cout << "Enter radius: ";
}
}

Circle::Circle(double xC, double yC, double rad) : x(xC), y(yC), r(rad)
{
   if (r < 0)
{
   cout << "Radius can't be negative\n";
   cout << "Radius set to 0\n";
   r = 0;
}
}

void Circle::centre_dist(Circle & c)
{
  if (((x - c.x) * (x - c.x) + (y - c.y) * (y - c.y)) < r*r)
{
  cout << "Точка принадлежит окружности." << endl;
} 
else 
{
  cout << "Точка не принадлежит окружности." << endl;
}
int main(){
Circle c1;
Circle c2(0, 0, 5);
cout << "centre distance: " << c2.centre_dist(c1) << endl;
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: подскажите в чем ошибка

Comment: Это вы нам подскажите что за ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны хотя бы указывать, о каких ошибках идет речь (что говорит компилятор, что вы хотели etc).

По вашему коду. Если бы вы хоть чуть-чуть форматировали ваш код, то увидели бы

```
void Circle::centre_dist(Circle & c)
{
    if (((x - c.x) * (x - c.x) + (y - c.y) * (y - c.y)) < r*r)
    {
        cout << "Точка принадлежит окружности." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Точка не принадлежит окружности." << endl;
    }
    int main(){
        Circle c1;
        Circle c2(0, 0, 5);
        cout << "centre distance: " << c2.centre_dist(c1) << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

что `main()` вы объявили **внутри** метода `void Circle::centre_dist(Circle & c)`.

Далее - вы хотите выводить

```
cout << "centre distance: " << c2.centre_dist(c1) << endl;
```

Какое значение вы хотите вывести, если `c2.centre_dist(c1)` - это вызов `void`-функции (см. фрагмент кода выше)?! Которая по определению не возвращает ничего! "Выведи мне ничто" - вот как это выглядит...

Исправите эти - ошибки - будет компилироваться. Будет ли работать - вопрос уже другой, на верность с этой точки зрения не смотрел (да вы и не спрашивали).

Comment: Функция main  попало в тело метода Вынесите функцию после.
Также выходит предупреждение, что double Circle::centre_dist(Circle & c) возвращает значение double. Но по сути я просто выводите же на экран через cout, ничего не возвращает функция. И в главной же функции вызываете его для вывода cout, а этот метод не возвращает значение

Comment: Поэтому нужно сделать
вывести main из тела метода centre_dist()
установить тип метода centre_dist() с double на void (не забудьте поменять в описании класса также)
в main вызвать метод, а именно:
cout << "centre distance: " << endl;
c2.centre_dist(c1); 
и нужно написать функцию(правильно)находится ли та точка в окружности или нет

Comment: моя проблема что мне подсказали ошибки но я не могу их исправить

Comment: А как я исправлю за вас? Ну, `main` я еще вынесу, но что я должен делать с вашим выводом `void`? Просто убрать эту строку? Как-то же вы это все написать сумели - ну, попробуйте подумать и исправить... Я же не знаю, что вам нужно (а честно - и знать не хочу, тут уже разжевано так, что любой троечник справится).

Comment: ну может вы свой вариант напишите (задание есть)

Comment: "Дайте воды напиться, а то так есть хочется, что даже переночевать негде"...